# Como puedo recibir dos datos con ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Utilizo ajax para cargar unas consultas que luego las recibo como echo, pero quiero recibir dos echos de los cuales quiero mostrar en diferentes html, con uno me funciona, pero no se como se haria el segundo,
este es mi ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#right').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "prueba.php",
        success: function(response,prueba) {
            $('#galeria').html(response);
            $('#info').html(prueba);
        }
    });
});
```

Y en el prueba.php tengo esto:

```
$guardar = "";
$guardar = "<div class='item active gallery-image'>
            <img id=".$row['idPhoto']."
            src=./uploads/".$row['urlPath']."
            class='gallery-image'/>
</div>";
echo $guardar;
echo "segundo dato a mostrar";
```

la variable $guardar me la muestra, pero como recibo el otro echo para mostrar en el html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso lo más simple sería mandar un JSON desde el servidor. Esto te permitirá mandar las respuestas organizadas, con una clave para identificar a cada una.

### PHP

```
$mData=array('uno'=>$guardar, 'dos'=>"segundo dato a mostrar");
echo json_encode($mData);
```

### Javascript

Es necesario indicar que esperas un json desde el servidor, mediante el parámeto `dataType`, y luego, buscas los datos diferenciados por sus claves:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#right').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "prueba.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#galeria').html(response.uno);
            $('#info').html(response.dos);
        }
    });
});
```

Si observas bien, la función de `success` **tiene un sólo parámetro (`response`)**, no dos parámetros. No se puede entender Ajax como algo que va y viene por cada `echo` que ocurre en el servidor. La respuesta viene una sola vez, y así debe ser, por eso conviene organizar toda la información que necesites en un solo objeto (en este caso `$mData`). Lo que estabas intentando es como si necesitarás dos productos que se venden en Australia y pagaras dos billetes de avión para ir a buscar cada producto. ¿Por qué no traerlos los dos en un solo viaje? Pues eso: Ajax es un viaje, entre cliente y servidor.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona y muchísimas gracias por la explicación ahora lo entiendo mucho mejor.